# Different permissions for different opportunity team roles

Tags: opportunity-teams

I am currently setting up team roles for my opportunities. Is it possible to give different roles on the team different permissions? For example, I don't want some of the team members to be able to edit a certain field. Is that possible via team roles?
Tia, Lily.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are a complex issue in Salesforce. AFAIK, you don't use opportunity teams for that, you use a mixture of profiles and permission sets.

If you just want to protect one field from modification, there are different approaches:

- Create a custom profile that has read-only access to a certain field, and then make the users that should have read access members of this profile.
- Make the field read-only for all profiles, and create a permission set with read/write permissions, and assign this permission set to the users who should have readonly access.

You could try using sharing rules but that would entail making the whole object readonly, which I don't think is really what you want.

I would greatly recommend spending some time watching the ["who sees what" series of videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3Hg6OXhPO8), which is a great resource to learn about this.